# Adding Label (Text box style) to Folium Output

Tags: python, folium

I have a folium map on which I am trying to add a textbox which I would always like on screen with additional details and can't seem to find a way to get one to popup.

I tried something like a colormap

```
import branca.colormap as cm
colormap = cm.linear.Set1.scale(0, 35).to_step(10)
colormap.caption = 'A colormap caption'
map.add_child(colormap)
```

or an image by the following

```
FloatImage(img_link, bottom=60, left=70).add_to(map)
```

It seems that adding a text box with 4/5 lines of information should be pretty simple, but I can't seem to find a way to overlay one over Folium. So I really hope someone could point me to the right direction.

The one idea I possibly had left would be to add in iFrame, but not too sure how I could get that to work.

Comment: I've seen examples of labels tied to specific coordinates.  Would that work?

Answer (score 3):

The following code should work:

```
import folium

from folium import IFrame

text = 'your text here'

iframe = folium.IFrame(text, width=700, height=450)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=3000)

Text = folium.Marker(location=[lat,lon], popup=popup,
                     icon=folium.Icon(icon_color='green'))
Yourmap.add_child(Text)

Yourmap.save('mymap.html')
```