# How can I add a text box to folium (with more or less the same behavior as the LayerControl panel)?

Tags: python, html, leaflet, folium

I want to add a text box to a folium map that gives more information about the source data and how the map can be used as a resource. If possible, I want it to look and behave almost identically with the LayerControl function (and a bonus would be if it were collapsible too).

(This is incidentally my attempted work-around for what I initially had wanted: the ability to hover over an icon next to each item in the LayerControl panel to display a popup infobox, but I suspect that this would be far more demanding, since it involves modifying folium.LayerControl).

So far, I have only been able to find solutions that [add a marker to the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771779/adding-label-text-box-style-to-folium-output), but this isn't really doing the same thing as a simple text box. [Other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65104927/add-text-to-folium-map-using-an-absolute-position) involve adding text at a specific location on the map, but I need the textbox to be displayed wherever the user navigates. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928013/adding-a-title-or-text-to-a-folium-map) is the closest solution I've come across to what I need, but this only adds text above the map, and I'm not sure that modifying the html code wouldn't be reducible to the same solution as adding text at a specific location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer gist

You can use [branca](https://github.com/python-visualization/branca) to inject HTML and CSS (can be used to add a custom legend, draggable too).

Here's a basic example based on this branca [demo nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/gist/talbertc-usgs/18f8901fc98f109f2b71156cf3ac81cd)

### Preview

[image: result preview]

You can see that I can customize even the title of the tab of the browser. In case your hosting the file on GitHub Pages or somewhere else, you can have your project name on the tab, add an icon... etc.

### Code

```py
import folium
from branca.element import Template, MacroElement
import webbrowser

# main map
m = folium.Map(location=[35, 38], tiles=None, zoom_start=3)

# adding a basemap
dark_basemap = folium.TileLayer("cartodbdark_matter", name="Dark Theme Basemap").add_to(m)

# Injecting custom css through branca macro elements and template, give it a name
textbox_css = """
{% macro html(this, kwargs) %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Textbox Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#textbox" ).draggable({
          start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css({
              right: "auto",
              top: "auto",
              bottom: "auto"
            });
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="textbox" class="textbox">
      <div class="textbox-title">Textbox (draggable)</div>
      <div class="textbox-content">
        <p>You can put whatever content here.<br>You can create as many elements and positon them all over the map.</p>
        <p>You can delete the script that makes it draggable and all script links that come with it.</p>
        <p>You can add a link to a local CSS file in the head and past the css in it instead of here.</p>
        <p>You can find a way to make it collapsible with JS or CSS, it's a normal HTML div after all.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
 
</body>
</html>

<style type='text/css'>
  .textbox {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    border-radius:4px;
    background: rgba( 28, 25, 56, 0.25 );
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37 );
    backdrop-filter: blur( 4px );
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 4px );
    border: 4px solid rgba( 215, 164, 93, 0.2 );
    padding: 10px;
    font-size:14px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    color: orange;
  }
  .textbox .textbox-title {
    color: darkorange;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    }
</style>
{% endmacro %}
"""
# configuring the custom style (you can call it whatever you want)
my_custom_style = MacroElement()
my_custom_style._template = Template(textbox_css)

# Adding my_custom_style to the map
m.get_root().add_child(my_custom_style)

# Adding the layer control
folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(m)

# save the map as html
m.save("m.html")

# opens in default browser
webbrowser.open("m.html")
```

I added  glassmorphism effect for the fun but you can do a lot with it.